# How do you stub and test a helper that invokes a different method depending on the object class passed to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, helper, minitest, stubbing

I've got this helper which I'm trying to write tests for in Minitest. The helper calls another method depending on the object class I'm passing as an argument, like so:

```
  def label_for(object)
      status = object&.status
      case object.class.name
      when "Subscription"
        class_for_subscription_status(status)
      when "Payment"
        class_for_payment_status(status)
      when "Purchase"
        class_for_purchase_status(status)
      when "Invoice"
        class_for_invoice_status(status)
      when "Ticket"
        class_for_ticket_status(status)
  end
```

Each individual method is already tested somewhere else, so I just need to test that if I pass a class `Subscription` object to `label_for`, it will invoke `class_for_subscription_status(status)` and not something else.

This is the test I've come up with, but I get ``` NoMethodError: undefined method ``class_for_subscription_status' for #<AuxiliariesHelperTest ``` errors.

```
  test "#label_for(object) should invoke the right helper if object is of class Subscription" do
    AuxiliariesHelperTest.any_instance.stubs(:label_for).with(subscriptions(:user)).returns(:class_for_subscription_status)

    assert_equal class_for_subscription_status(subscriptions(:user).status), label_for(subscriptions(:user))
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the whole classes? Is a little bit hard to guess with just this snippet.

One of the problems I see is that you are stubbing a method from the `AuxiliariesHelperTest` class, instead of the `AuxiliariesHelper` class.

Another possible issue is that your helper seems to be a module and not a class, and you should include the helper in your test file. Or your test class should inherit from `ActionView::TestCase`. Something like this might help:

```
class AuxiliariesHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  include AuxiliariesHelper
 

  test "#label_for(object) should invoke the right helper if object is of class Subscription" do
    AuxiliariesHelper.any_instance.stubs(:label_for).with(subscriptions(:user)).returns(:class_for_subscription_status)

    assert_equal class_for_subscription_status(subscriptions(:user).status), label_for(subscriptions(:user))
  end
end
```

Although in my opinion, you should not stub the method, but expect that the correct method is called:

```
class AuxiliariesHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  include AuxiliariesHelper
 

  test "#label_for(object) should invoke the right helper if object is of class Subscription" do
    AuxiliariesHelper.any_instance.expects(:label_for).with(subscriptions(:user).status)

    label_for(subscriptions(:user))
  end
end
```